# One arm bends incorrectly but the other is fine

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-weights

I made two arms, one of the two being a duplicate with ScaleX =-1. I placed the armature one the right side and used Symmetrize to mirror it on the other side. Then I set parent with automatic weights, but when I go into pose the right arm bends correctly when I move the upper arm bone while the other twists around. I have no idea why it does this.
Thanks.

[image]

File:

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Read the instructions and share the link here, or use another platform like workupload

Comment: I added link to file at the end of my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the transforms, as you have negative scale values it will flip the normals, you need to recalculate them in *Edit* mode, then parent again *With Automatic Weights* and it will work.